# HTMLHelp uses not Tahoma even when HTML page specifies tahoma

Tags: windows-xp, chm

Some HTML pages placed into CHM file. Firefox displays them ok with Tahoma font (HTML have Tahoma specified for entire file). But CHM file shows not Tahoma font (maybe it shows Arial, not sure).

Issue only on WinXP. W7 is OK. 
Can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve found. If i change HTML encoding from `charset=iso-nnnnnnnnnn` to `charset=windows-1251` then OK.